# How to create a DELETE endpoint in IFTTTT for different users

Tags: iot, endpoint, ifttt

I need to create a DELETE end-point in IFTTT as suggested in the documentation (https://platform.ifttt.com/docs/api_reference#trigger-identity). The DELETE endpoint is given as

`{{api_url_prefix}}/ifttt/v1/triggers/{{trigger_slug}}/trigger_identity/{{trigger_identity}}`
so here the end-point needs the value of `{{trigger_identity}}`. Here the `trigger_identity` is a **unique signature of a specific user, trigger, and trigger fields** and it varies accordingly. So with as many users of ifttt that many DELETE end-point would be needed which is practically not possible. I need to have like a single DELETE endpoint of IFTTT that will catch all the delete request when user disconnects or archives the applet. Is there any solution to this issue? Thanks in advance for all the inputs.

Comment: What do you base the assumption that `So with as many users of ifttt that many DELETE end-point would be needed`? Think of the identity trigger as a request parameter.

Comment: Here the {{trigger_identity}} is different for different users so the endpoint value which depends on {{trigger_identity}} would be different.

Comment: You create the endpoint once and the value of slug and identity is different for every request: they are variables. :)

Comment: That is correct the slug and identity are variables, but how do i pass these values to the end-point. I thought of creating a function that with slug and trigger_id as parameters, but this function is never called during disconnect. Only the DELETE end-point receives the value during disconnect.

Comment: If possible can u please share a code snippet for this flow